Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app)., js engine: hermes
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "......",
  authDomain: "uvm20f20699.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: ".......",
  storageBucket: "uvm20f20699.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: ".........",
  appId: "......",
  measurementId: "........"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

i am install firebase before
